# Does the halfer position in the Sleeping Beauty problem make for an irrational gambler?

Tags: logic, epistemology, probability, thought-experiment

It's my understanding that the [Sleeping Beauty problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleeping_Beauty_problem) doesn't have a consensus answer, with major camps along the lines of "halfers," "thirders," and "the-question-statement-is-ill-defined-ers." However, I'm curious what the halfer positions have to say about the following gambling-related interpretations of credence.

If P is a proposition, let G(P) be the gambling game consisting of paying $40 for the chance to win $100 iff the proposition P is actually true. The point being, if P is expected to be true with probability 1/2, a profit-motivated participant should play G(P), but not if P is expected to be true with probability 1/3.

(1) If one asks Sleeping Beauty to play G(P) where P = "The coin landed heads" upon waking up, I think even a halfer has to concede to act "like a thirder" and decline the game. (At least this is what my friend, a halfer, has conceded, and is the only reasonable choice in my eyes.) But this is also not a perfectly fair demonstration, since the nature of the game constrains Sleeping Beauty to play and lose *twice* if P fails to be true.

(2) If one instead considers the reformulation of Sleeping Beauty (known as the "Sailor's child problem" in the wiki) where one is a lifelong orphan but one knows one's parents made a 50% random choice to have either one or two children, one can consider a similar game, where P = "I am an only child." This game is such that one *will not* be constrained to lose twice if wrong. And yet, if an enterprising individual offered this wager to every halfer orphan in this circumstance, he would stand to make a $20 profit per three contestants.

The only way I can think to reconcile the contradiction is if halfers either reject the equivalence of these two thought experiments, or reject the connection of degree-of-belief to gambling strategy altogether.

Comment: Both halfer and thirder positions have Dutch books against them and so are "irrational", see [Titelbaum, p.1008](https://compass.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/phc3.12080). The problem is that both Dutch books have some suspicious traits and "*the jury is still out on which of these Dutch Strategies – if either – reveals a genuine rational inconsistency... Briggs (2010) argues that causal decision theorists should embrace the Dutch Strategy against halfing (and become thirders), while evidential decision theorists should embrace the strategy against thirders (and so be halfers).*"

Comment: @Conifold Interesting. I'll definitely check that paper out. His Dutch Book against halfers, however, seems to be the same as my (1), which I do think is suspicious, because the beauty knows the probability of being wrong on Tails-Monday is not independent of being wrong on Tails-Tuesday; a halfer needn't pre-accept both bets, IMO. At any rate, do you believe there's anything suspicious regarding my (2) game?

Comment: Why you're not one of "the-question-statement-is-ill-defined-ers"? Then your contemplated contradiction of halfers would dissolve itself?...

Comment: @DoubleKnot I'm either a thirder or an ill-defined-er; I'm not really confident. But I know smarter people than me are halfers, and I want to hear their explanation :)

Comment: @DoubleKnot I wouldn't be for the same reason that "the Liar is meaningless" does not go very far. One needs a theory of meaning that would deliver that while endorsing "meaningful" sentences, and none on offer is satisfactory. The Sleeping Beauty is analogous. There are perfectly well-defined decision problems that become "ill-defined" on any theory that classifies the Sleeping Beauty as such.

Comment: @Conifold I don't feel this puzzle and the liar is at the same theoretical deepity level, even if there are perfectly well-defined decision problems that become "ill-defined", it's not that surprising since decision theory touches many aspects of practical problems such as utility, probability of events. If Head event is 1 green ball  placed and Tail event is 2 red balls, one really needs to choose "what is the probability 2 red balls were placed in the box" and "what is the probability 1 red ball was drawn from the box". The problem just lacks linguistic clarification of which one is asked...

Comment: @DoubleKnot I think I feel the same way Conifold does (although that's up to him to corroborate), that quantities like P("today is Monday") really /should/ be well defined, and to dismiss them as ambiguous because the very best decision theory we have is only robust enough to handle sentences about nice and simple experiments involving red and green balls rather than self-locating epistemic agents, would lead me to suspect the decision theory is incomplete.

Comment: If it's that deep it should've been much more famous attracting much interest to answer your post compared with current statistics. "today is Monday" is not a formal proposition in logic as 'today' is indexical linguistically, not a distinct context-free event in a definite 4-D lightcone of the block universe with its well-defined sample space per Kolmogorov's spec. Similarly sleeping beauty self-locating epistemic agent just exposed an intrinsic ambiguity of the anthropomorphic principle when applied to physics or AI as it's not its own creator though may *wish* to decide with uncertainty...

Comment: Viewed in this way sleeping-beauty problem is a somewhat interesting epistemic philosophical puzzle but not surprised or totally unexpected. And the halfer does have some advantage compared to the thirder in terms of Occam's razor since you can safely equate each wakup of the sleeping beauty as a completely new person is born and asked that question, and the generic new person only needs to know a single simple 50% credence for a fair coin flip without the assumed *additional* prior knowledge of the setup of the problem, then of course the halfer is smarter since her context is simpler...

Comment: When I said "nice and simple," I didn't mean to disparage the mathematical maturity of any theories. They might be all that is required for analyzing anything in a given formalism of a mechanistic universe, but if they can only respond with profound uncertainty about e.g. P("I have cancer" | "the test was positive") or the decisions I really should take following a positive test, I consider it an incomplete analysis of... something important I find difficult to articulate.

Comment: Ironically if everything is completely determinable via reason alone as a non-designer, is there any need for a 'decision theory' in the sense of agent free will?...

Comment: To the extent that human behavior will never practically be reduced to predictions from the Standard Model, and to the extent that we still have no clue how consciousness arises or what it's made of, I should still think so, yes.

Answer (score 1):

> The only way I can think to reconcile the contradiction is if halfers either reject the equivalence of these two thought experiments, or reject the connection of degree-of-belief to gambling strategy altogether.

My previous answer assumed that the proposition could be freely chosen, but even if it is always "head wins" you kinda changed the scenario by making it a bet or taking the perspective of the bookie.

Like in the case of (1) you could compute the different outcomes and it would be:

- +$60 if you bet on heads and it comes up heads
- -$80 if you bet on heads and it comes up tails

So if the odds are indeed evenly distributed you'd lose $10 per game on average. So you would not play the game, but unlike the thirders you'd not do it because you think that heads is less likely, but because the payout scheme is stacked against heads.

In terms of (2) it's slightly different because now it's not the same person being asked in case of tails. So from the perspective of the individual being asked it's just:

- +$60 if the coin flip landed heads
- -$40 if the coin flip landed tails

That the bookie gets +$80 for tails as he gets to prompt more people is insignificant to the perspective of the individual being asked.

So there is no contradiction, there are no halfers acting non-halfer-like and their action isn't less rational than that of the thirders.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. We seem to be on the same level now, but for the consequences of the halfer mindset in (2). It doesn't have to do "prompting more people" necessarily; if the bookie takes just a single random orphan from this population and they enter into this bet, the bookie can be expected a profit and the orphan can be expected a loss. I know of no other situation where this is considered rational behavior, but this appears to be a winning game in the orphan's eyes if he is a halfer.

Comment: @Feryll the crucial problem is that these 3 options don't exist simultaneously. So if for every coin toss the bookie goes out and offers the bet to exactly 1 person then they will either only have 1 person to ask (cause the coin landed heads) or they'll have 2 ("equivalent") people because the coin landed tails. They'd never actually be in a position where there are 3 people of whom two are in the tails caseand 1 in a heads case. So as a consequence if the bookie only asks once per coin toss, he'll lose money with the 60/40 bet as it's actually just a coin toss bet with extra steps.

Answer (score 1):

The Sleeping Beauty Problem, as usually stated, breaks with conventional probability theory by allowing the number of observations of an outcome to depend on that outcome. This is why gambling arguments will never resolve it. There is no established way that one can interpret the meaning of this difference. While I agree with your interpretation, it is not provable because there is no basis for such a proof. I believe that the original intent of the thought problem was to help establish such precedent, but that can only be done by proving an answer without relying on interpreting the difference.

That can be done. The Sleeping Beauty Problem, as usually stated, is not the actual Sleeping Beauty Problem. It was originally posed in private discussions by Arnold Zuboff, and made public by Adam Elga in his 2000 paper "Self-locating Belief and the Sleeping Beauty Problem." Both are referenced in the Wikipedia article you linked. Elga stated it this way (Zuboff's is different only in the number of potential wakings):

> Some researchers are going to put you to sleep. During the two days that your sleep will last, they will briefly wake you up either once or twice, depending on the toss of a fair coin (Heads: once; Tails: twice). After each waking, they will put you to back to sleep with a drug that makes you forget that waking. When you are first awakened, to what degree ought you believe that the outcome of the coin toss is Heads?

Notice that Monday, Tuesday, and most importantly the difference in what can happen on each named day, are not mentioned. Elga introduced those elements, in how he *implemented* the experiment, to create his thirder solution. Halfers question the validity of his treatment. And it is all unnecessary. There is a better implementation.

I'll keep the day names, since they don't matter. The random elements are that on Sunday night, after SB is put to sleep, we flip two coins. Call them C1 and C2. On Monday Night, regardless of what has happened so far, we turn coin C2 over to show the opposite side. So regardless of the day, there are four equally-likely combinations for what is shown: {HH, HT, Th, TT}.

The observation elements are that on both Monday and Tuesday morning, the researchers examine the two coins. If both are showing Heads, they let SB sleep thru the rest of the day. But if either is showing Tails, then (1) they wake SB, (2) they ask SB "What is your credence now for the proposition that coin C1 is currently showing Heads?", (3) after SB answers, they put her to sleep with amnesia.

This way, an awake SB knows that her observation is dependent on the combination HH being eliminated. She would not be awake if the coins were showing HH, and the remaining three all remain equally likely. Since coin C1 is showing Heads in only one of those three, her "credence" in that circumstance must be 1/3.

This proof is inarguable. Which is probably why the only argument which is made against it has been that I have changed the problem. The fact is, that I changed it less than Elga did, and neither changes any of pertinent details. (Mine essentially uses coin C2 to determine whether Elga's Monday, or Tuesday, could be the day SB sleeps thru.)

The answer is proven to be 1/3. Halfer's need to come to grip with why their arguments are invalid.

Comment: A crucial difference between your experiment and Elga's is that you would gain information from waking up. And that is kind of the point that you could move from a reasonable position of halfer before the experiment to a not completely unreasonable position of thirder within the experiment despite no new information. You learn nothing new from being awake as you knew beforehand that this would inevitably happen. Also HH is not eliminated you'd just wake up on Tuesday which you couldn't distinguish from Monday, right? And it could be the first time being awake or the second time.

Comment: Most of this doesn't directly respond to my question, but I do appreciate (and am further convinced by) your reformulation of the problem. When you say "this is why gambling arguments will never resolve it," what do you say about my hypothetical (2), where the gambler is /not/ exposed to multiple observations? I still find that the most convincing argument to date.

Comment: haxor789, the difference between the two camps is that thirders think information is gained, and halfers do not. Asserting that there is no gain is not an argument against my point. Which is to show that, and how, information is gained. You do not learn *just* that an awakening is happening, which you knew would, you learn that conditions which support an awakening are happening. Now, if you think that either my version, or Elga's, do not correctly implement the problem as he published it, I'd love to hear why. Or if you think my solution is incorrect. If not, the answer is proven to be 1/3.

Comment: Feryll,, I disagree about Sailor's Child being the same problem, although halfers want to claim it is. Because "Tuesday&Heads" exists in the SB problem, but "The other child" does not exist if the Sailor's coin came up Heads. AND, SB experiences both days if it is Tails, but the child has has no equivalent. A better example for SB is to wake her both days. But on Tuesday after Heads, you don't ask her a probability question. You take her on a trip to DisneyWorld. This addresses the halfer's misconception that the two days have no meaning, but SB has the same information when she is awake.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that there are *halfers* (who believe the probability of heads is 1/2) and *thirders* (who believe that the probablity of heads is 1/3) indicates that there is confusion over whether the two events - heads on the coin toss *and* Sleeping Beauty being awake - are probabilistically *dependent/independent*. The two events are independent if the probability of heads given that Sleeping Beauty finds herself awake is 1/2 (no change in the probablity of heads on the coin toss, its initial probability is 1/2 and it stays 1/2 even after Sleeping Beauty is woken up) and dependent if the probability of heads is anything other than 1/2 (there's a change in the probability of heads from 1/2 to 1/3 in the case of thirders).

**Bayes' Theorem**
P(H|A) = Probability of heads given Sleeping Beauty is awake
P(A|H) = Probability that Sleeping Beauty is awake given heads = 1 (she's woken up if the coin shows a heads)
P(H) = Initial probability of heads = 1/2
P(A) = Probability that Sleeping Beauty is woken up = 1 (she *is* woken up)
P(A & H) = P(H & A) = The probability that Sleeping Beauty is woken up *and* the coin toss was a heads.
P(A & H) = P(H & A) = P(H) * P(A|H) = P(A) * P(H|A)

That out of the way, let's calculate ...
P(H|A) = [P(H & A)]/P(A) = [P(H) * P(A|H)]/P(A) = (1/2 * 1)/1 = 1/2
P(H) = P(H|A) = 1/2. That is to say the two events (heads on the coin toss *and* Sleeping Beauty awake) are *independent* events.

So far so good ...

---

P(H & A) = P(A & H) = P(T)

1. **P(T) = P(H) * P(A|H) = 1/2 * 1** (already explained)
2. **P(T) = P(A) * P(H|A) = 1 * 1/3** [There are 3 outcomes and they are (Heads, Monday, Awake), (Tails, Monday, Awake) and (Tails, Tuesday, Awake) and Sleeping Beauty can't tell which of these is the case just by being awake]

As you can see, P(H) * P(A|H) != P(A) * P(H|A). **This is the issue!!!**

P(A & H) = P(A) * P(H|A) = 1 * 1/3 = 1/3
P(H & A) = P(H) * P(A|H) = 1/2 * 1 = 1/2

---

*Attempt at Conflict Resolution*
P(H|A) != 1/3. In other words, that there are **3** events/outcomes (mentioned above) is an *illusion*. There are only **2** viz. (Heads, Monday, Awake) and (Tails, Monday, Tuesday, Awake). Mathematically, we would say that we've *overcounted*, in this case the *possibilities*.
We have to establish the *identity relation* (Tails, Monday, Awake) = (Tails, Tuesday, Awake). I suppose that in terms of *coin toss outcome*, *both are identical* (both are tails) i.e. it doesn't seem to matter whether it's Monday/Tuesday for coin toss outcome. In a sense then, (Tails, Monday, Awake) = (Tails, Tuesday, Awake) with respect to coin toss outcome (both tails). The conclusion seems inevitable ... (Tails, Monday, Awake) and (Tails, Tuesday, Awake) are *not* 2 events but actually the *same* 1 event, and once more ... there'll be peace in the galaxy.

Comment: This conclusion seems flawed...  You say waking up Monday and Tuesday are 1 same event.  But the whole question is to consider what sleeping beauty can conclude when she is woken up.  On a tails toss, waking Monday and Tuesday are _clearly_ two separate events.  She cant wake up once and have it be both days.

Comment: @JMac, 1) It's Monday. Sleeping Beauty doesn't know if the coin toss was heads/tails. 2) It's Tuesday, Sleeping Beauty knows its tails. 3) It's tails, Sleeping Beauty doesn't know if its Monday/Tuesday. Only if Sleeping Beauty knows it's Tuesday will she be able to tell the outcome of the toss as tails.

Comment: I'm not sure what that has to do with my comment.  Im also not sure what you mean with 2). Sleeping beauty doesnt know the day or the result of the coin toss no matter what the toss was or what day she is awake.

Comment: No, the existence of halfers and thirders means there is disagreement over whether "DAY=MONDAY" and "DAY=TUESDAY" can be used as probabilistically independent events. Here's three examples that can illustrate it. Assuming the same drugs are used as in the popular version: (1) Use an 6-sided die instead of the coin. Wake SB exactly once, on the Dth day after Sunday. When awake, can she legitimately say that Pr(Thursday|A)=1/6? If not, why not? (2) Roll two dice, and re-roll until they are different. Wake her as before, but now twice. Is Pr(Thursday|A) 1/6, 1/3, or undefined? (Continued).

Comment: (3) Finally (and this is modeled after how Marilyn vos Savant explained the Monty Hall Problem intuitively), roll an N-sided die for any N>=2. Wake SB D times over the next D consecutive days. What is Pr(D=1|A)? Note that if N=2, this is the popular problem. Thirders should say Pr(D=1|A)=1/(N+1), and Halfers should say Pr(D=1|A)=1/2. The question for intuition, especially if the answer to #2 is 1/3, is if N=1,000, shouldn't you really feel more confident in a large number?

Comment: There is no tails for Tuesday. P(heads) is not the same as P(Heads & Monday)? *Cogito*.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean, Agent Smith. The coin result exists, regardless of what that result is, on both Monday and Tuesday. SB's capability to observe it (or rather, the lack of the capability on Tuesday if it is Heads) does not extinguish Heads&Tuesday, it means that SB has the information that there is a member of the sample space that has been eliminated. That is usually called "new information," and is used to update probabilities.

Comment: "There are only 2 viz. (Heads, Monday, Awake) and (Tails, Monday, Tuesday, Awake)." So, if the event is (Tails, Monday, Tuesday, Awake), and we tell SB that it is Tuesday, then it is also Monday? If not there clearly is a difference between (Tails, Monday, Awake) and (Tails, Tuesday, Awake). (continued)

Comment: A better way to show this is to use four SBs, Each is given, but can't reveal, a different combination in (H/T, Mon/Tue) when she will be left asleep. The three who are wakened are brought together and asked for their individual Pr in "your H/T." Which is obviously 1/3 since there are three awake and only fits. But to solve it with conditional probability, they can't use your "combined" event since that works differently for each. They need four, each has prior Pr of 1/4, and a conditional Pr of 0 or 1 for waking given that event.

Answer (score 0):

If one is waking up, then one does not know if it is Monday or Tuesday.

The probability of waking Monday is 100% and the coin options are both H and T. This gives us two events, M-H, and M-T where one awakes.  The probability of waking on Tuesday is only 50%, as T-H will not involve waking, but T-T will.

When SB wakes up, it will therefore be one of three options, each with the same probability:  M-H, M-T, T-T.  The probability of the coin being heads is 1/3.  This is the thirder solution.

Note there is no need to invoke speed of light cones, nor indeterminacy claims.

Comment: The Wednesdays shouldnt count for the SB problem.  On Wednesday she is not being asked anything, so theres no reason to assume its relevant, she would not be asked to gamble on Wednesday and would know the test is over.  Alternatively, I'm pretty sure it would work if she never woke up again after Monday/Tuesday, but that's a bit too dark.

Comment: @JMac  Thanks for the correction!  Thirder it is then.